# Simplify my vector data to display it more efficiently

Tags: qgis, gdal, simplify

I have >1Billions points data (in geoparquet but could gpck) that I have to display in QGIS in a scale that doesn't need such precision (=we will not see all the details). It takes age to load in QGIS and I have then to create an export from layout manager which I guess will take forever.
Where can I look for to simplify my input data so it is adapted to the scale I am displaying it?

I have seen ogr2ogr with -simplify option but it seems to limit the precision but not reduce the number of points, so I am not sure it is the way to go.
I have also think that gdal_rasterize could be an option, but no so sure either

Any hint?

Comment: pick the first 1000 points? pick every 100th point? - we need to know how your points are distributed and what they represent and what you plan to do with them to make a more informed answer

Comment: I dont know what geoparquet is, but having a very big geopackage can be slow to display. I usually export/import the data to PostGIS and create a spatial index. Then it will display faster in QGIS

Comment: @IanTurton it represents GPS tracks (but now it is more GPS points) from outdoor enthusiast. I have a bout >1billions of points which cover France and I want to display the whole France

Comment: The "simplify" argument does things like make polygons less detailed. You can't really "simplify" points in that way. If you want to display a billion points you have to display a billion points - but really you won't see much except a big blob of smushed points. So maybe, depending on the function of your map, count the points in 1km grid squares and make a raster?

Comment: @Spacedman could you elaborate on your proposal? how to count on a 1km grid?

Comment: You can do this in QGIS. If you really want to do that then first search for a solution (eg "QGIS count points in grid squares") online then if you can't find that then post a new Q here.

Comment: Use Sedona/Spark, run DBSCAN with multiple distance thresholds representing zoom level density, and create a new dataset with the cluster centroids and their respective zoom level identifier. Can be done in a single job. Together with proper indexation, you might be able to use these in RDBS storage (or GPKG) as source for live maps.

Comment: If you still have the source GPS tracks you can use GPSBabel to reduce the point density of the tracks.

Comment: @geozelot seems dbscan implementation exists in Qgis, will look at it. Clustering is indeed a possible solution to my problem

Comment: It does, but neither QGIS, nor even PostGIS does well with that payload. If you can, use a distributed engine to create higher level core data derivates. GeoParquet is made for that.

Comment: @geozelot my data are already in geoparquet. Except for the creation, Indo not see much improvment in the reading. But maybe Qgis implementation is not yet optimal

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest approaching your problem with the tools for handling Lidar datasets. These tools are optimized for dealing with billions of points, as you have. One such set of tools is `pdal`, also available within QGIS, I believe. Using `pdal` you can try one of two filters to subsample the points, leaving a much smaller set. One filter is `sample` ([sample documentation](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.sample.html)) which will give you a random sample of the original points. The other filter is `decimation` ([decimation documentation](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.decimation.html)) which, as the name suggests, removes nearby points until a desired density is achieved.

There's another procedure, a bit more complex, that you can consider: The LASTools set of utilities has a tool `lasthin` that performs a similar job as above, but with some additional options to determine what is filtered out. [Here's](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/sToPDXIwLIE/m/-OzOACpZAgAJ) an explanation by Martin Isenburg (RIP) from a few years back of how to use that tool.

Comment: Interesting! it also permits me to discover similar tools included in SAGA... will evaluable all of that